# "Module not found" for typescript-only library in Angular compiler

Tags: angular, angular-aot, angular-cli-v8

I have an Angular application that I am switching over to use the Angular compiler. This application uses a library that I also created, which was built and packaged using webpack.

When I try to build the library using `ng build --prod`, there is an error:

```
ERROR in ./source/typescript/application.module.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '<library name>/typings/library/dispatcher' in 'C:\Development\Applications\<app name>\source\typescript'
```

I verified that the files it is looking for are there. It is kind of odd that it wants to include `.d.ts` files. My app builds and runs without warning or errors using webpack. What am I missing?

Comment: I see my issue has been found by others here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4874. No resolution yet though.